# Как содержимое файла преобразовать в список объектов

Tags: python

Есть список объектов dataclass вида:

```
b = [Animal(n=1, id=1, animal=['шотландец', 'сфинкс', 'манчкин']), Animal(n=4, id=2, animal=['овчарка', 'бульдог', 'сфинкс', 'ориентал']), Animal(n=1, id=3, animal= ['овчарка', 'корги', 'воробей'])]
```

Содержимое этой переменной я записываю в текстовый файл.

Как открыть файл так, чтобы это была не строка, а такой же список объектов, как в переменной b?

Пробовала делать следующее:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open("t.txt", "r") as f:
    result = literal_eval(f.read())
```

Здесь создается список, но элемент списка в виде строки, что так же не является решением моей задачи.
Нужно чтобы я по индексу могла обратиться к элементу списка, то есть при b[0] получить "Animal(n=1, id=1, animal=['шотландец', 'сфинкс', 'манчкин'])"

Comment: Есть такая прекрасная функция как `split` разделите обьекти и сформируйте нужный вам список из них

Comment: Покажите скрин записи в текст файл

Comment: хоть split и создает список, но внутри списка элементами являются так же строки. как я писала в условии, мне такое не подходит.

Comment: суть в том, что я получила этот список объектов в одном месте. просто скопировала результат в файл и теперь данные из этого файла надо использовать в другом месте. и мне нужно понять как именно считывать данные из файла, чтобы можно было обращаться к ним

Comment: У вас свой кастомный объект (не надо называть его dataclass это никому ничего не говорит), который вы как-то записываете в текст, поэтому вам придётся писать свой кастомный парсер для чтения файлов.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/saving-an-object-data-persistence

Comment: @Эникейщик, автор имеет ввиду, что у него там экземпляры класса, которые он создавал через модуль `dataclasses`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, похоже, что вам поможет [консервирование](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). Работает это примерно так:

```
import pickle

with open(filename, 'w+b') as f:
    pickle.dump(b, f)  # консервация

with open(filename, 'r+b') as f:
    b = pickle.load(f)  # расконсервация
```